# Science Fiction (novel?) involving robotic feline pets named Pookas?

Tags: story-identification, robots

This was a case of me finding this in the process of doing research for my question, but I figured I'd post it. Somehow, the subject of [pookas](https://www.yourirish.com/folklore/irish-pookas) came up in a conversation at work, and I mentioned that, as a teenager, I associated that name with robots because of something I'd read where robotic cats were named that, and it got me to wondering what piece of fiction it was.

The main character had one, and it was a bit of a security blanket for her, originally given as a therapy pet, but which she continued to cling to as she became an adult. There's a scene that sticks out in my memory where she felt abandoned (I can't remember if she actually was), and it had her tightly hugging the "pooka", crying into its fur as it purred to try to console her. I think there was mention of having to replace its synthetic fur frequently because her constant handling of it was leaving it threadbare.

Comment: Aside: [Púca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%BAca).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[The Rowan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rowan)* by Anne McCaffrey.

After my initial searches for *science fiction robotic cat pooka* didn't bear much fruit, I realized that I sometimes spelled it a different way, "pukha", and I did another search, and *science fiction robot cats pukhas* brought up [this article](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/Science-Fiction-News.asp?NewsNum=5311).

> Or, the company calls the Qoobo a "tailed cushion that heals your heart". Not a headless robot cat. How does it work? You "storoke" it.
>
> > **A Tailed Cusion (sic) That Heals Your Heart**
> > Qoobo is a therapeutic robot in the form of a cushion with a tail. When caressed, it waves gently. When rubbed, it swings playfully. And, it occasionally wags just to say hello. It's comforting communication that warms your heart the way animals do. Begin your "tail therapy" today and wrap yourself with fuzzy love.
>
> I think this is a simplified version of what Anne McCaffrey called a "Pukha" in her 1990 novel *The Rowan*:
>
> > Pukhas, deriving their name from the imaginary companions discovered by needful children, had become widely used in pediatrics. They could be programmed for a variety of uses, but more often were used in surgical and long-term care with great effect and as surrogates for intense dependency cases...

And indeed, that matches with the electronic text I found:

> ...Once the child was recovered from the physical effects and the sedative dosage had been reduced, Lusena had taken her to select a pukha toy from the hospital's supply. Pukhas, deriving their name from the imaginary companion discovered by needful children, had become widely used in pediatrics. They could be programmed for a variety of uses, but more often were used in surgical and long term care with great effect and as surrogates for intense dependency cases. The Rowan child needed her own pukha. Considerable thought had been given to its programming: its long soft hair was composed of receptors, monitoring the child's physical and psychic health. It could, receiving danger signals from the Rowan, initiate pacifying sentiments, encourage conversation and, of paramount importance, moderate the little girl's mental `voice'. It also responded with its soothing, rumbling purr when the little girl became restless or distressed. although Lusena and the pediatrics staff would...

A mention of replacing the fur:

> .... Three times the feline had to be peeled from
> the sleeping child to replace its furry covering, worn or damaged
> receptors, and to update its programming.

The destruction of the robot, which results in her getting a live "barquecat":

> Moria was crouched in one corner, knees drawn up to her head, her
> arms wrapped over it, whimpering in jagged little cries.  The Rowan
> stood in the center of the room, her face a mask of grief, of
> unimaginable sorrow as she stood, clutching the Purza's head, its fur
> shorn in hunks about her, its dismembered limbs cut into many pieces.